Add event MouseMove or MouseClick to get cursor position on inserted picture
I inserted picture using this code:
Sub InsertMyPicture(PicPath As String, wsDestination As Worksheet)
    Dim Pic As Picture, Shp As Shape
    Set Pic = wsDestination.Pictures.Insert(PicPath)
    Pic.Name = "Map_1"
   
    Set Shp = wsDestination.Shapes("Map_1")
    With Shp
        .Height = 2800
        .Width = 3000
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue  
        .Placement = 1
        .Top = 1
        .Left = 1
        .OnAction = "PicX"
        
End With

And I can't find how to set event handler to this object "Map_1" I need x,y cords according to inserted picture (when user clicks some point on picture I put mark there and save it x,y in cell)
Best regards.
I 've tried onAction method (PicX) and it works only as I click I can get .Left nad .Up values wchich are -5 -6 and not show actual mouse cursor position.
